# Convert long date text to date / time

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup

I have an Excel (2010) spreadsheet delivered to me which is basically a text dump.

Cell - J8 has the following info **Tue Feb 4 00:08:06 EST 2014**
Cell - L8 has the following info **Tue Feb 4 00:14:54 EST 2014**

I need to calculate the difference in time between L8 and J8.

These cells are formatted as "text" and since they have the day, date, time and "EST" formatting the cells with long date it doesn't work.

Comment: Is the format always the same? `<3-letter day> <3-letter month> <day> HH:MM:SS EST YYYY`?

Comment: If possible I would go back to the source and ask for a better format in the first place instead of working on a parser.

Comment: Yes - the format is always the same.  The text file was a data dump from a "vendor" and they are VERY reluctant to run it again.

Answer (score 1):

Uses an array (column of months MMM, and 1-12) and can surely be improved, but to tide you over:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(J8,4),VLOOKUP(MID(J8,5,3),array,2,0),MID(J8,9,2))+VALUE(MID(J8,11,9))
```

in say Y8 and copied across to Z8 with `=Z8-Y8` in AA8 may suit (for the 'time' being!)

Does not cater for differences in time zones.

Answer (score 1):

I did this to parse the date/time value of each cell:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(J8,4),VLOOKUP(MID(J8,5,3),$P$2:$Q$13,2,FALSE),MID(J8,9,LEN(J8)-26))
+TIME(MID(J8,11+LEN(J8)-27,2),MID(J8,14+LEN(J8)-27,2),MID(J8,17+LEN(J8)-27,2))
```

Then you can just do a simple subtraction between the values of the two cells.

The only thing I needed to add to the spreadsheet was a lookup table to map month name to month value. Hence the `VLOOKUP` in the formula.

I also needed to calculate the offset position past the day value as it appears that it could have either one or two digits - hence the magic `26` and `27` numbers in the formula.

Comment: Using this gets a result "NAME?"

Comment: @user3285970 - Then you spelt something wrong. Did you copy and paste from my answer?

Answer (score 1):

If L8 is always later than J8, and if the format is always as you show (with three letters for the timezone, and the spacing as above, then try:

=(MID(L8,5,6)&", "&RIGHT(L8,4) &" "& MID(L8,11,9))-(MID(J8,5,6)&", "&RIGHT(J8,4) &" "& MID(J8,11,9))

One further caveat with this method: your native default date (in Windows Control Panel, not in Excel itself) needs to be MDY as in your text dump.

**EDIT**:  The following (longer) version should work no matter if your native date format is MDY or DMY:

```
=(MID(L8,9,2)& MID(L8,4,4)&RIGHT(L8,5)&" "&MID(L8,11,9))-(MID(J8,9,2)& MID(J8,4,4)&RIGHT(J8,5)&" "&MID(J8,11,9))
```

Comment: Thanks for picking up on that.  I didn't realize the conversion was not picking up the year.  I will change it.

Comment: My dates are MDY (like the examples) so I guess it is a locale issue.  And yes, it looks like I am subtracting strings, but since they "look like" a date, Excel coerces them to date/time values.  I have 2007 also. Oh, and I did check with both single and double digit dates, and, at least with MDY it works OK.  With a single digit date, there will be a space after the date, but Excel sees the comma before the year, so that extra space gets ignored.

Comment: Using =(MID(L8,5,6)&", "&RIGHT(L8,4) &" "& MID(L8,11,9))-(MID(J8,5,6)&", "&RIGHT(J8,4) &" "& MID(J8,11,9)) I'm getting "0:06" as a result from time of 00:33:54 and 00:37:56 which is a time difference of 00:04:02